# Howr to make music from Parse I uploaded play shuffled?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, shuffle

This is what I have so far:

```
              let query = PFQuery(className: "Genres")
              //Find objects in the background
               query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        //store objects in an array
        (objectsArray :[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let objectIDs = objectsArray
        // objects being added to array
        for i in 0...objectIDs!.count-1{
        // add a new element in the array
        self.iDArray.append(objectIDs![i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
        //store song name in song array
        self.NameArray.append(objectIDs![i].valueForKey("SongName")as! String)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        NSLog("\(objectIDs)")

        }

    })
}

func grabSong () {
    let songQuery = PFQuery(className: "Genres")
    songQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block: {
        (object: PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

        if let audioFile = object?["SongFile"] as? PFFile {
            let audioFileUrlString: String = (audioFile.url)!
            let audioFileUrl = NSURL(string: audioFileUrlString)!
            AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: audioFileUrl)
            AudioPlayer.play()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What par is not working specifically? Give us a bit more info...

Answer (score 0):

one possible approach (based on your code)

1. Shuffle the `iDArray` (how to shuffle an array can easily be googled.)
2. set `SelectedSongNumber` to 0 after you load the idArray
3. then, whenever you call `grabSong`, increment `SelectedSongNumber` by 1
4. if `SelectedSongNumber` < `iDArray.count` proceed with loading the song, else you're done
5. observe AVPlayer and when it finishes playing an item, call `grabSong` again (how to observe the player can be found here on SO)

that should shuffle all you like :)